# Expo EAS Submit, where to store service account key

Tags: expo, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I am looking into using EAS (expo Application Services) to submit a build to the Google Play Store. As per the docs, a `serviceAccountKeyPath` is required:

https://docs.expo.dev/submit/eas-json/#serviceaccountkeypath

I have successfully submitted a build by running `eas submit -p android` and entering the path to the JSON service account key when prompted.

As this is sensitive information, I don't want it to be added to my git repo. Should I just add it to my .gitignore, or is there a better way e.g. store it within my expo account somehow?

Comment: Did you endup storing the application service credentials somewhere ? I was thinking to store it as a secret file in expo which will give you the path to the file as environment variable but Im not sure how to replace this during eas submit

Comment: I just added it to my .gitignore file. Not ideal, but works for now.

Comment: does this key work for all apps or do I need only one

Comment: I wonder what people do for automated delivery with github actions

Answer (score 10):

You can avoid needing to set `serviceAccountKeyPath`, even with your first call to `eas submit`, by uploading your credentials in the Expo UI.

From your project dashboard in the Expo UI:

1. Choose "Credentials" from the navigation on the left.
2. Under the Android tab, choose your Application ID (usually set in your `app.config.js` file)
3. Choose "Add a Google Service Account Key".
4. Upload the Google Service Account Key JSON file. If you haven't created one yet, follow [their instructions](https://expo.fyi/creating-google-service-account).

Now the Google Service Account Key will be stored in Expo and you don't need to figure out how to store it in your repository, CI system, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to provide `serviceAccountKeyPath` the first time you run `eas submit -p android` for an specific project. You have to do manually the first time. The next you run `eas submit` expo takes the previus provided file.

Comment: Could google service key json file be available in the repo where is the code? What are security concerns as there are a lot of data inside the json. Can file be called as a secret in the eas.json somehow?
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#iam-service-account-keys-create-console

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do that while running eas submit, you can upload the service key on expo dev and when your run eas submit it just picks the service key you uploaded. To add the key to the project look at the credentials section of a project and look for the `Google Service Account Key` section.